# The number of distinct integers in an array is O(log n). How to get an O(n log log n) worst-case time algorithm to sort such sequences?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

The question is from the The Algorithm Design Manual. I have been working on it but haven't found a method to arrive at the right answer.

Question:
We seek to sort a sequence S of n integers with many duplications, such that the number of distinct integers in S is O(log n). Give an O(n log log n) worst-case time algorithm to sort such sequences.

I think maybe can first pick all these distinct elements and form an array of logn length and then record the frequency and sort it. However the my first step seems to blow up running time too much...Is any superior selection method or is my method totally wrong? Thanks

Comment: "I think maybe can first pick all these distinct elements and form an array of logn length and then record the frequency and sort it." Sounds reasonable to me except perhaps the choice of data structure. "However the my first step seems to blow up running time too much" Could you explain?

Comment: Do you have any information of duplications in sequence S?  Why can you assume O(log n) distinct integers in S??  n distinct integers in S may possible.

Comment: Let ***X*** be the number of distinct integers, which happens to be *log n*. Then the problem is asking for an algorithm that sorts in ***O(n log X)***. After you solve your problem, replace ***X*** with ***log n***.

Comment: just a silly idea but to get distinct integers then you have to go through whole array so it is at least O(N). O(N) case needs O(M) space where M is full range of used numbers (for 32bit ints you need 2^32 counters). If you use lists then the time complexity will go very bad due to list search and inserts. To ease up the space complexity the array is first sorted which is O(N.Log(N)) and then just search for duplicity which is O(N) so together you get `O(N.log(N))` and not `O(log(N))` so check your question text if you did not made mistake somewhere ... or am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260673/sorting-an-n-element-array-with-ologn-distinct-elements-in-onloglogn-worst-c?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

Use a balanced binary tree to calculate the number of occurrences of each number. Since there are only log N distinct numbers, the size of the tree is log N, and thus all operations is performed in log log N. (this is exactly how map<> is implemented is C++)

Then, just iterate the nodes of the tree in a pre-order traversal, and print each integer the required number of times in this order.

Comment: Thank you. But could you give me some hints for creating a balanced binary tree from an unsorted array using less time than O(nloglogn)?

Comment: Sure, just start with an empty balanced binary tree, and for each integer: 1) check if its already in the tree, and if it is, then increment its counter by 1. 2) otherwise, insert it to the tree. Since each operation is O(log log N), this is O(N log log N)?

Answer (score 4):

Create an array containing pairs of (unique numbers, count). The array is initially empty and kept sorted.

For each number in your original array, look the number up in the sorted array using binary search. Since the array has size O (log N), the binary search each time takes O (log log N), you do that N times, total O (N log log N). When found, you increase the count.

When not found, you insert the new number with a count of 1. This operation only happens O (log N) times, and is trivially done in O (log N) steps, for a total of O (log^2 N), which is much smaller than O (N log log N).

When you are done, fill the original array with the required numbers. That takes O (N).

There's really no need to create a balanced sorted tree to make the insertions faster, because the set of unique numbers is so small.

If the set of integers is all contained in a range X ≤ number ≤ Y, then the problem can be solved in O (max (N, Y - X + 1)) using an array of X - Y + 1 counters and not even bothering to find unique numbers. The technique is reportedly used to great effect in Iain Banks' book "Player of Games".